# How to start a new row in Angular 2 templat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular

I'm working on Angular 2 now. In my template I'm using the following to show the data I get from the APIs

```
<div class="blocks">
  <div router-active class="block" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="inblock">
      <p class="title">{{ item.name }}:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine but if one of the div height was higher than the others it would look something like the image below

[image: The wrong display of the blocks]

I want to have a nice row with three divs only and after three you start a new block, I know how to do it normally but I can't figure out how to do it with Angular 2!

**UPDATE** : I don't want a fixed height because the content can be as long as the user wants! so adding a fixed height with CSS will not solve the issue

Comment: Can you post your css please?

Comment: It's not a css problem, it's like a counting problem. I need to know how to tell Angular to close the div and start a new one after printing three values @tmutton

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari that's a css problem

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari The solution can be found using css. I have posted a potential answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You will find a solution using css. Take this code:

```
.block {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}

.block:nth-child(3n+4){
  border: 1px solid red;
  clear: both;
}
```

The above code is using float to make the blocks inline. Using nth-child you can tell it to clear each 3rd block.

Comment: I don't want a fixed height! that's why css will not solve the issue, thank you though

Comment: "I want to have a nice row with three divs only and after three you start a new block". That is a css issue and my solution using nth children will help solve your problem.

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari look at the usage of the css flex(box). That will solve your issues with ease

Comment: Have you tried the above code? You don't have to use the fixed height property - I've taken it out. The important bit above is the nth-child method. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a 'css' associated to your template and pass it to `styleUrls` property. In that CSS you can defile a class and set the div properties whatever you like and pass that class name to the elements.

Comment: it's not a CSS problem